# Angular.js Search Query if search form is out of current file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I had this code on index.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid people-container">
    <div class="search">
        <!--Sidebar content-->

        <span class="search-text">Search:</span>
        <input ng-model="query" class="search-input">

        <span class="sort-text">Sort:</span>
        <select ng-model="orderProp" class="sort-select">
            <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
            <option value="age">Date</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="people-listing">
        <!--Body content-->

        <ul class="people">
            <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail person-listing clearfix">
                <a class="clearfix" href="#/people/{{person.id}}">
                    <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{person.imageUrl}}">
                    <div class="person-info">
                        <h1 class="title">{{person.name}}</h1>
                        <span class="year">{{person.born}} - {{person.died}}</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I decided to divide the UI into partials, and moved the search part to **search.html**:

```
<div class="search">
    <!--Sidebar content-->

    <span class="search-text">Kërko:</span>
    <input ng-model="query" class="search-input">

    <span class="sort-text">Radhit sipas:</span>
    <select ng-model="orderProp" class="sort-select">
        <option value="name">Alfabetit</option>
        <option value="age">Vitit</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Before doing this, the search form was working great. After I moved it to another template, it doesn't work. I have no idea because this is my first day working with Angular.js, and I'd need some help. Also, here's what on my **controllers.js**:

```
var deshmoretControllers = angular.module('deshmoretControllers', []);
deshmoretControllers.controller('PeopleListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Person',
  function($scope, Person) {
    $scope.people = Person.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);

...
```

Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/J98O34dBFaUchhKdT6ck

Comment: have you done ng-include for partial

Comment: Yes, I have included the header, and into the header, again included the search form like this:

<div ng-include src="'search.html'"></div>

Comment: can you setup a plunker that would be easy to solve then

Comment: @HarishR I added the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/J98O34dBFaUchhKdT6ck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the code.. there were lots of issues in it.. [WORKING PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ya3quGxhNYJVVmc6vocw?p=preview)

```
1. you need ng-controller which covers both search & results, you kept the controller on just each box & not on list
2. make sure that you ng-model never uses value without dot, rather than query - use variable as search.query
2b. make sure to initialize the search object in controller $scope.mysearch = {};
```

I did below modification

> 1. moved controller to list.html rather than search.html
> 2. init $scope.mysearch = {} in controller

Comment: Perfect! I made some small modifications and it's just how I wanted it to be. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

We this is a prototypal inheritance problem. 
Assuming you are moving the template and referencing it with `ng-include`. `ng-include` creates a new scope.
You set your `query` in the new scope, not in the parent scope that is part of  `PeopleListCtrl`

To fix it define the query as object on the parent scope

`$scope.query={term:''}`

Then reference this as query in partial search.html

`<input ng-model="query.term" class="search-input">`

In this way the child scope can manipulate the object properties defined on parent.

As long as the parent child relationship is there you can now access the update query data in the parent scope.

Also the declaration of ng-controller=`PeopleListCtrl` should be on the parent element of where the search.html is inserted if used. If the controller is injected using $route definition then nothing needs to change.

Since the `query` has changed to object all reference should be to now `query.term` like

`ng-repeat="person in people | filter:query.term | orderBy:orderProp"`

To know more about prototypal inheritance and scopes see this wiki https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Can you send code of where exactly should I define the new query? Right now, I added it into the PeopleListCtrl controller, but it's not working.

Comment: Where is PeopleListCtrl defined?

Comment: controllers.js, I already added the code for that controller in the question.

Comment: I was asking the declaration for ng-controller. Or are you using routeProvider?

Comment: I tried to define it at **<div class="search" ng-controller="PeopleListCtrl">**, but it's not working

Comment: Since your query has changed to object you need to use this in you `ng-repeat`. `<li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:query.term | orderBy:orderProp"`

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. Here's the plunker, can you try fixing it there? http://plnkr.co/edit/J98O34dBFaUchhKdT6ck

Comment: You added controller on search that was not required. Also please go through the wiki link, it would help you a lot.